# how to create a break in text and put in different cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I create breaks in a long line of text?

I need the text to be in different cells (currently all in one with no breaks)

Example:

`AU654AU789AU321AU544` needs to be split into different cells:

`AU654` `AU789` `AU321` `AU544`

Comment: You could save the file as a CSV and then use a scripting language to break it into pieces. Do you have Ruby, Python, Perl, or the like installed?

Comment: is there always a constant amount of characters? i.e. `2 letters` and `3 numbers`? or does it vary? You can use willus' answer but if that big string always looks the same. If not, you will be looking at a more complicated macro with a split algorithm or a regex

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**MID()** function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mid.php)

The format is MID(string,start position,number of chars).

For example:

if you put that string in cell `A1`, then in cell `B1`, you can put `=MID(A1,1,5)`, and in `C1`, you can put `=MID(A1,6,5)`, and so forth (assuming the line can be broken at fixed widths).